# The error message when I am attempting to install a domain controller on the forest mysite.com

Tags: powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

[image]

This is the error message when I am attempting to install a domain controller on the forest mysite.com.

00domaincontroller.ps1

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module ServerManager
Enable-PSRemoting -force  

$DCPromoFile = 
@"
[DCINSTALL] 
UserDomain="mysite.com"
UserName="Administrator"  
Password="password1234"
ReplicaOrNewDomain="Replica"
ReplicaDomainDNSName="mysite.com"
DatabasePath="c:\Windows\NTDS" 
LogPath="c:\Windows\NTDS" 
SYSVOLPath="c:\Windows\SYSVOL"
InstallDNS="Yes"
CriticalReplicationOnly="No"
ConfirmGC="Yes"
SafeModeAdminPassword="password4321"
RebootOnCompletion="Yes"
"@ 
$DCPromoFile | out-file "c:\folders\dcpromo.ini" -force
```

Comment: So ... does `c:\folders` actually exist?

Comment: yes it is just a replacement for the actual.

Comment: What do you mean, "a replacement for the actual"?  The error message says that it doesn't exist - does it or doesn't it?

Comment: The actual is similar to C:\Users\User1\Documents\dcpromo.ini  I just do not want to divulge my data online.

Comment: It is an empty folder I could not find it in a search.

Comment: What's the point of posting a screenshot if it doesn't show the actual problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Yes that ran without an error.  How do you check if the domaincontroller  ran?